# Universal method to dl files from url

Tags: python, web-scraping, download

New developer, old guy, first time poster.

Many websites make files available for download. Is it possible to write a universal python script to handle most any html / file formats? Feed it a website, it downloads the files. Seems like beautiful soup or something similar could work?

Example websites include:

CSV: CBOE ( e.g., https://www.cboe.com/us/futures/market_statistics/historical_data/)

ZIP: Project Gutenberg (e.g., https://www.gutenberg.org/files/98/)

JPEG: Unsplash (e.g., https://unsplash.com/)

I've seen various posts for specific sites, but nothing that's universal.